# How to draw animation between screens flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a fitness app for a school project, and what I found is that when I create several exercise screens, there is an animation when you press a button to move on to the next exercise. How can I get this animation out.

This is what happens:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSJwF.gif)

This is my code: (the code of the other exercises are the same what changes is the content)

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as prefix0;
import 'package:circular_countdown_timer/circular_countdown_timer.dart';
class ActivityTimer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image = 'assets/images/1.gif';
  final String tag = 'imageHeader';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
          return (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation ==
                  prefix0.Orientation.portrait)
              ? Portrait(image: this.image, tag: this.tag)
              : Landscape(image: this.image, tag: this.tag);
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Portrait extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image, tag;
  CountDownController _controller = CountDownController();
  bool startStop = true;    
  Portrait({@required this.image, @required this.tag});    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Hero(
              tag: this.tag,
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 270,
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/1.gif",
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 40,
              right: 20,
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.7),
                  ),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 30.0, 20.0, 20.0),
          height: size.height - 270.0,
          width: size.width,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Saltar à Corda',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 28.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Próximo: Subir à Cadeira',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          color: Colors.grey[300],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                        child: CircularCountDownTimer(
                          duration: 11,
                          controller: _controller,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fillColor: Colors.red,
                          backgroundColor: null,Circle
                          strokeWidth: 5.0,
                          strokeCap: StrokeCap.butt,
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 22.0,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          isReverse: true,
                          isReverseAnimation: true,
                          isTimerTextShown: true,
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => _controller.start(),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 70.0,
                        height: 55.0,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 9.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(232, 242, 248, 1.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.play_arrow,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(82, 126, 255, 1.0),
                          size: 35.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => _controller.pause(),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 70.0,
                        height: 55.0,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 9.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(232, 242, 248, 1.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.pause,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(82, 126, 255, 1.0),
                          size: 35.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) {
                              return SubirACadeira();
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: size.width - 200.0,
                        height: 55.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(232, 242, 248, 1.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                          'Próximo',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(82, 126, 255, 1.0),
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          ),
                        )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Landscape extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image, tag;

  Landscape({@required this.image, @required this.tag});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Stack();
  }
}
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation is due to `Navigator.push`, since when you push a new screen, the animation appears. You can try to keep all state in just one screen. If you use a `StatefulWidget` instead of a `StatelessWidget`, you can only change what's need to be changed. Here's an example of how it can be done:

```
class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  String title = "Saltar à corda";
  String subtitle = "Próximo: Subir à cadeira";

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(title),
        Text(subtitle),
        TextButton(
          child: Text("Próximo"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              // Here you can define the next title and subtitle
              title = "Subir à cadeira";
              subtitle = "Próximo: Flexões";
            });
          }
        ),
      ]    
    );
  }
}
```

This is a minimal example but it can help you to understand how you can do this. You can also create a list to keep track of all titles and subtitles:

```
class ScreenData {
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  
  const ScreenData(this.title, this.subtitle);
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  // ...
  static const List<ScreenData> _data = [
    ScreenData("Saltar à corda", "Próximo: Subir à cadeira"),
    ScreenData("Subir à cadeira", "Próximo: Flexões"),
    ScreenData("Flexões", "Próximo: Abdominais"),
    ScreenData("Abdominais", "Próximo: Prancha"),
    // You can add more here
  ];
  
  // Start with the first element of the list
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  // Data containing the title and subtitle of the current screen
  ScreenData get _currentData => _data[_currentIndex];

  // ...

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(_currentData.title),
        Text(_currentData.subtitle),
        TextButton(
          child: Text("Próximo"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              // Update the current index
              // Beware when _currentIndex == _data.length
              ++_currentIndex;
            });
          }
        ),
      ]    
    );
  }
}
```